# How to pass XCOM values to PythonVirtualenvOperator op_args?

Tags: airflow, airflow-xcom

So I am trying to pass arguments to **op_args** of **PythonVirtualenvOperator** using **xcom_pull**.
But I am not quite sure how to do it properly. Any help would be highly appreciated.

*I am not sure how to provide more details, but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to create post otherwise.So please ignore this line*

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonVirtualenvOperator, PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.hooks.base import BaseHook
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from test_process import process_test_data


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'catchup':False    
}

connection = BaseHook.get_connection('test_flow')
db_user = connection.login
db_pass = connection.password


    
with DAG(
    'test',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(1)  
) as dag:

    
    
    process_test_data_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id = 'process_test_data',
        python_callable = process_test_data,
        op_args = [db_user, db_pass, ti.xcom_pull(key='db_host'), ti.xcom_pull(key='db_database')],
        python_version=3.8,
        system_site_packages=True,
        requirements = ['psycopg2', 'configparser'],
    )

    process_test_data_task
```

Comment: what is the source of "db_host" and "db_database", it should come from a task if you are using ti.xcom_pull.

Comment: @ozs Hi! I pushed them once and now they are in my airflow XCOM list.  I didn't wanna keep this task runing because as it turned out it didn't overwrite those key-value pairs  it just added a new one with each dag execution.

Comment: If its constant value that you want to use you can store it as Variable and then it will be availabe to all tasks and dags. Or you can take it from the connection that you took user and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue and was able to pass arguments using jinja templates.

If the values you want to pass are constant, you should follow ozs's advice and store them as Variables. In my case they were not, so after pushing the values to XCOM I needed to pass it to the virtual env. In your code it would be something like:

```
        process_test_data_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
            task_id = 'process_test_data',
            python_callable = process_test_data,
            op_args = [
                db_user, 
                db_pass, 
                '{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='db_host') }}', 
                '{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='db_database') }}'
            ],
            python_version=3.8,
            system_site_packages=True,
            requirements = ['psycopg2', 'configparser'],
        )
```

Careful: as far as I could tell, templated args will always be converted to strings within the PythonVirtualenvOperator.